# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not owned by

Tags: pulseaudio, 23.10, hp-pavilion, helpfile

Installing latest Ubuntu on HP Pavilion Desktop and erasing Windows 10 but the install has stalled on " Install libgtk2.0-0 (amd64).

When I click on it, a small command screen comes up with:

> XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999!(This could eg happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)

How do I solve this problem?